# DML Exception not being caught

Tags: apex, error, error-messages, dmlexception, try-catch

```
ClassA {
     Method1() {
         Method2();
     }
     Method2() {
         ClassB.Method3();
     }
}
ClassB {
     Method3() {
          //Failing DML Operation
     }
}
```

How come I can only catch exception in method3 and method2 but not in method1? I implemented try catch in all methods and rethrew the exceptions but it never reaches method1 (I can see it reaches method2 and method3 via debug). Even with only try catch in method1, it never reaches method1.

I need it to reach beyond method1 because the proper error handlers are outside. (Returning jsonresponse, error logs, integration logs).

Can someone explain why? Is there a workaround? Other additional info:
The logs:

```
10:53:25.23 (237181263)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[151]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STRING_TOO_LONG, Nickname: data value too large:  (max length=40): [CommunityNickname]

10:53:25.23 (240949240)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STRING_TOO_LONG, Nickname: data value too large:  (max length=40): [CommunityNickname]
```

Comment: Can you show us how did you implement try catch in above class A and B?

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.